# What message handler to use for modifying "static data" maintained within a singleton bean?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, declarative

I'm using a singleton bean to hold certain "static data" that is evaluated at the API start and may get updated from time to time.

I'm setting the bean initially as a map in the context:

```xml
<util:map id="staticData" key-type="java.lang.String" >
    <entry key="keyA" value="#{null}" />
    <entry key="keyB" value="#{null}" />
</util:map>
```

The `staticData` values are then updated periodically.  For the updates, I'm currently using header-enricher, for lack of a better idea.

```xml
<int:header-enricher>
    <si:header name="dummyHeader" expression="@staticData.put('keyA', payload)" />
</int:header-enricher>
```

This "works" but seems inelegant and also creates a `dummyHeader` with no utility.

Would you recommend a better approach to this mechanism?

Thanks for any pointers and best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds more like just a `service-activator`:

```
<service-activator output-channel="nullChannel" expression="@staticData.put('keyA', payload)" />
```

Indeed `header-enricher` is about modifying a request message for downstream processing.

What you need is just update external store and forget. Of course you may have a requirements to store that data there and continue your flow. For that purpose you can use a `<publish-subscribe-channel>` and have two subscribers where one is exactly that service-activator.

We have to use that `output-channel="nullChannel"` to ignore a result of the `Map.put()` call.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#service-activator

Comment: I agree that it's a service-activator pattern.  I'm really wanting to call this from within a chain without affecting the current message. Calling a service activator requires quite a bit more setup from within a chain.  

Perhaps I'll need to write a custom transformer that maintains the current message while executing an additional expression with side-effects.